# How to preserve html comments in rendered output

Tags: custom, rendering

We are creating custom forms in Sharepoint designer by replacing the listview webpart by customized xslt markup inside a dataformwebpart. The xslt contains html comments which we need to be rendered in the browser similar to what is rendered using the standard listviewwebpart. How can we get the comments included in the rendered output ?

an expample section of the xslt is ....

```
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" colspan="2" style="white-space: normal;"><H3 class="ms-standardheader" style="white-space: normal;">title</H3></td>
          <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" colspan="18">
      <!-- FieldName="title"
        FieldInternalName="_x0073_itle"
        FieldType="SPFieldText"
      -->
            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="_x0073_itle" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@_x0073_itle')}"/>
            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="_x0073_itle" ControlMode="New"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be easy !! just use an  block as in .....

```
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" colspan="2" style="white-space: normal;"><H3 class="ms-standardheader" style="white-space: normal;">title</H3></td>
      <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" colspan="18">
  <xsl:comment> FieldName="title"
    FieldInternalName="_x0073_itle"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
  </xsl:comment>
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="_x0073_itle" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@_x0073_itle')}"/>
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="_x0073_itle" ControlMode="New"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
```